# Image_picker failed to load images from gallery

Tags: flutter, imagepicker

everything is good but when i try to get picture from gallery using 3rd party program (es file explorer) image picker plugin get this error Unable to decode stream: java.lang.NullPointerException
i tried again with many pictures
,and get the same result.

Comment: try `flutter clean` and rebuild the app

Answer (score 0):

To fix the error, follow these steps:

1. Update all your dependencies in pubspec.yaml, including
   image_picker,
   using the command `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions`. Make sure that your Flutter SDK is also updated to the newest version 3.10.0 or above.
2. Stop your app
3. Run the command flutter clean.
4. Run the command flutter pub get.
5. Run the app

If my answer helped you, please don't forget to vote ️.